# Anonymous function conversion

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-function

C# Language Specification **6.5 Anonymous function conversions** states that:

> ...
>
> Specifically, an anonymous function F is compatible with a delegate type D provided:
>
> ...
>
> If F does not contain an *anonymous-function-signature*, then D may have
>   zero or more parameters of any type, as long as no parameter of D has
>   the out parameter modifier.

However, the following code generates errors.

```
using System;
namespace DelegateAnonymousFunctionExample
{
    public delegate void D(int i, int b);
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Valid
            D f1 = (int a, int b) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked...");
            };
            f1(3, 4);

            // Error
            D f2 = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked...");
            };

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
   }
}
```

Where did I go wrong in the above code?

Comment: Can you provide link to this spec?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029. This is a download link, not sure if there is an online version.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @John ''Delegate 'D' does not take 0 arguments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$6.5 of spec you pointed also says:

> The expression does not have a type but can be implicitly converted to
>   a compatible delegate type or expression tree type

and $6.5.1:

> Conversion of an anonymous function to a delegate type produces a
>   delegate instance which references the anonymous function

Anonymous method just can be defined with lambda-expression,
actually, these things are different.

[Lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/lambda-expressions) has no type and can be implicity converted to [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/), used in [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/index) query expression and [Anonymous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods) method definition.

So, in your error case lambda expression **will be converted to incompatible delegate instance** that accepts no args.

**Quote from spec you provided** says about

```
D f5 = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked..."); };
```

It works because signature is not pointed and it will be automatically compiled to compatible delegate instance which accepts (int, int).

**"If F does not contain an anonymous-function-signature"** means **signature absence**, but lambda's **'()'** means **signature which accepts no args**. And lambda can't be declared without signature as it mentioned in @Johnny's answer. About delegates examples: take a look on 4th example in code sample - it is invalid, because has incompatible signature which accepts no args, 5th example has not signature and it is valid.

You also can copy sample below and check how it will be compiled (just comment invalid code prior)
**https://sharplab.io/**

```
public delegate void D(int i, int b);

public void Main(string[] args) 
{        
    //valid, lambda expression will be converted to compatible delegate instance
    D f1 = (int a, int b) => Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked...");
    f1(3, 4);

    //INVALID, lambda expression will be converted to incompatible delegate instance
    D f2 = () => Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked...");
    f2(3, 4);

    //valid, assigning delegate with compatible signature
    D f3 = delegate(int i, int j) { Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked..."); };
    f3(3, 4);

    //INVALID, assigning delegate with incompatible signature
    D f4 = delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked..."); };
    f4(3, 4);

    //valid, it will be automatically compiled to compatible delegate instance which accepts (int, int)
    D f5 = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Delegate invoked..."); };
    f5(3, 4);
}
```

Comment: That is weird. In the spec, if I remember correctly, anonymous functions include anonymous-method-expressions and lambda expressions.

Comment: Lambda expression actually has no type and can be implicitly converted to expression or anonymous method, give me some time, I almost found reason...

Comment: The spec uses the term "anonymous function", which could be anonymous method or lambda expression. Section 6.5 Anonymous Function Conversions clearly states that in the first sentence. So using lambda expression shouldn't be the cause of the error. However your reasoning that "It works because signature is not pointed and it will be automatically compiled to compatible delegate instance which accepts (int, int).", imo, is the key to the answer. There is simply no way, syntactically, to write a lambda expression without parentheses, whose presence implies a signature.

Comment: @woldmar so in effect, lambda expression is ruled out in this case. I accepted your answer.

Comment: @JohnSmithSr., I think just "*If F does not contain an anonymous-function-signature*" means signature absence, but lambda's '()' means signature which accepts no args. Also lambda can't be declared without signature as it mentioned in Johnny's answer. About delegates examples: take a look on 4th example in code sample - it is invalid, because has incompatible signature which accepts no args, 5th example has not signature and it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

The `f2` variable is not receiving a valid method signature, you delegate `D` is waiting for 2 parameters.

Comment: Hi, so how so you  interpret the spec?

Comment: Can you explain how that satisfies the second part of the spec defined in the question?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP was meant to ask the same on how to perceive the spec

Comment: Intuitively I would say the same thing. But based on the spec, at least my understanding of it, it should not generate errors. so there is misunderstanding somewhere I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

> A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type

In principle everything start from `delegate`, and it says **particular parameter list** and **return type**.

> If F does not contain an anonymous-function-signature, then D may have
>   zero or more parameters of any type, as long as no parameter of D has
>   the out parameter modifier.

The anonymous method can be declared using the syntax `delegate` *parameter-list* `{` *statement-list* `}`. Here you can omit the *parameter-list* in that case what above says is valid. On the other hand if you supply parameters then parameters type must match exactly.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int a);

MyDelegate d = delegate { }; //valid
MyDelegate d = delegate(int a) { }; //valid
MyDelegate d = delegate(int a, int b) { }; //invalid

public delegate void MyDelegateOut(int a, out int b);
MyDelegateOut d = delegate { }; //invalid
```

---

If you want to declare `delegate` using lambda, the omit effect cannot be archived as the syntax is (*input-parameters*) `=>` `{` *statement-list* `}`

Comment: thanks, your post is of great help, especially the last part.